# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED neo4j-community-3.3.1 on windows 10

Tags: neo4j

I installed neo4j-community-3.3.1 on Windows 10 as a Windows service on C:\neo4j-community-3.3.1.

I followed instructions from [installation site](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/). I install the service with "*bin\neo4j install-service*" and start it with "*bin\neo4j start*" [as shown in this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIHhf.png).
I am getting the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED errors when I opened the URL http://localhost:7474

How can I open the URL http://localhost:7474 to start working with Neo4j. I really appreciate any help.